# Script task failing sometimes when running through SSMS

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an SSIS package which contains Script task component. The SCR sends an email when it finds any new tags in the Database. The package is working when running through SSIS. When I deployed it in SSISDB it is running everyday and it is successful sometimes. But sometimes the job is failing throwing a error as SCR - Send an email Error. Syntax error,.....
When I tried to run it multiple times individually through job its working sometimes and failing sometimes. I don't know why it's behaving strangely.

[image]

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        //User::varEmailMessage,User::varMail_Body,User::varMail_Subject,User::varSendMailCC,User::varSendMailFrom,
        //User::varSendMailTo,$Package::strMailHost,$Package::strMailPassWord,$Package::strMailUserName

        string MailTo = Dts.Variables["User::varSendMailTo"].Value.ToString();
        string MailFrom = Dts.Variables["User::varSendMailFrom"].Value.ToString();
        string MailCC = Dts.Variables["User::varSendMailCC"].Value.ToString();
        string EmailMessage = Dts.Variables["User::varEmailMessage"].Value.ToString();
        string MailBody = string.Empty;
        //string MailSub = string.Empty;

        MailBody = @" " + EmailMessage ;
        
        EmailFunction(MailTo, MailBody, MailCC);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    public void EmailFunction(string MailTo, string MailBody, string MailCC)
    {
        string username = Dts.Variables["$Package::strMailUserName"].Value.ToString();
        string password = Dts.Variables["$Package::strMailPassWord"].Value.ToString();

        string MailSub = "Production Missing Tags List for " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        string EmailTo = MailTo;

        string body = MailBody;

        SendEmail(username, password, EmailTo, MailSub, body, MailCC);
    }
    public void SendEmail(string username, string password, string EmailTo, string MailSub, string MailBod, string EmCC)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(username);
            mail.Subject = MailSub;
            mail.Body = MailBod;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            if (EmailTo != "")
            {
                if (EmailTo.Contains(";"))
                {
                    string[] toList = EmailTo.Split(';');
                    foreach (string EmailAddress in toList)
                    {
                        if (EmailAddress != "")
                        {
                            mail.To.Add(EmailAddress);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mail.To.Add(EmailTo);
                }
            }
            if (EmCC != "")
            {
                if (EmCC.Contains(";"))
                {
                    string[] ccList = EmCC.Split(';');
                    foreach (string EmailAddress in ccList)
                    {
                        if (EmailAddress != "")
                        {
                            mail.CC.Add(EmailAddress);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mail.CC.Add(EmCC);
                }
            }

            var client = new SmtpClient(Dts.Variables["$Package::strMailHost"].Value.ToString(), 587)
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials=false,
                Credentials=new NetworkCredential(username,password),
                EnableSsl=true
            };
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)

        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Main()", ex.Message, "", -1);  // Raise the error event to SSIS,
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;            // and report the task failed.
        }

    }
    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: I have no idea what the acronym SCR stands for (my Google-Fu gives "Silicon controlled rectifier" which I doubt is correct for this context), but it seems relevant to the question and probably should be tagged,

Comment: Have you used the `Send Mail Task` component? How did you configure the smtp settings? Does the machine you are having the error on have access to the smtp server?

Comment: @Larnu SCR is script task

Comment: @MostafaNZ I'm not using the Database mail. I'm sending the mail through script task in SSIS. I just have to debug the errors in the job.

Comment: WHy not reference it by what it *is* in your question then; SCR isn't an abbreviate for "Script Task", so of course we're going to have no idea what it means. If it is a script task, as well, then you need to include the code within it; the error telling you the problem, but you need to actually include the code and tag the language you are using.

Comment: @Larnu I have added the code now

Comment: Does the number of recipients impact when it fails, either in the To or in the CC?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz No they are not. The mail is either sent successfully to everyone or completely failing for everyone

Comment: Can you test using gmail as the smtp server?  You might be able to rule out any issues with your script that way.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I have tested with Gmail as well. It is still the same.

Comment: Next, could you check the data?  I'm wondering if there are some malformed email addresses.  Are there any input rows that fail consistently?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz The package is working fine with the same parameters when running in SSIS. It has something to do with the SSMS when running through job